# Simple PHP: Select & Show Column not working

Tags: php, mysql

I need to show Data from today from a certain column. Can anyone help? Nothing appears. Thanks! Connection seems to work.

```
    <?php
$db = mysqli_connect("server", "username", "pw", "database");
if(!$db)
{
  exit("Verbindungsfehler: ".mysqli_connect_error());
}
?>

<?php
$abfrage = "SELECT type FROM customers WHERE DATE(time) = CURDATE()";
$ergebnis = mysql_query($abfrage);
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($ergebnis))
   {
   echo "$row->Spaltenname";
   }
?>
```

Comment: You should also provide the database schema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the query problem, you have another problem with your code, you used mysqli_connect, then you started to use the old **deprecated** mysql_* methods.

```
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
error_reporting (-1);
$abfrage = "SELECT * FROM `customers` WHERE DATE(`time`) = CURDATE()";
$ergebnis = mysqli_query($db, $abfrage);
echo mysqli_error($db);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($ergebnis))
{
   echo $row->Spaltenname;
}
```

Comment: Pipped me too it, nice job :)

Comment: Nice, did this. Thanks for that. Still not working :(

Comment: Thanks @DanBelden, my first answer! :D

Comment: I added new lines to debug your problems, the first to lines will enable displaying any syntax error or warnings.

The fifth line used to debug your query and will print an error message if there is a problem with your SQL query.

Comment: Great! Thanks. Error now: Unknown column 'time' in 'where clause' Warning: mysqli_fetch_object() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /mnt/webn/a0/66/54215366/htdocs/form/Umsatz.php on line 16

Comment: great!,, now you have a problem with your SQL query are you sure that you have a column called "time"? double check your table structure and everything going to work fine

Comment: Solution found: $abfrage = "SELECT type FROM customers WHERE date >= CURRENT_DATE() ORDER BY type DESC";

Answer (score 0):

Your query is only retrieving the "type" column.

```
$abfrage = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE DATE(time) = CURDATE()";
```

Potentially expanding the columns in your SELECT may fix this?

- Always worth trying the query on the DB directly, before implementing it in any code.

Goodluck.

Comment: I've also just noticed you're using mysqli to connect and then standard mysql to query. If you try the following functions: mysqli_query() and mysqli_fetch_object() you may see your results.